# Insertion & Deletion at Specific Position in Single Linked List

Tags: c#, linked-list

Can any one give me an idea how to insert or delete a node from a specific position.
Please explain it with a sample code so that i can understand it well..
Thanks

Comment: -1 seriously mate if you can't work out how to search for this you won't get anywhere in software: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

Comment: i have implemented insertion , deletion at first and last node... at specific position i have no idea how to insert it

Comment: Please read it:[faq](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: @SalmanKarim And if we implement it for you you'll continue to not know how to insert or delete an item at an arbitrary position of a Linked List.  You should work through the problem yourself to properly learn how to do it.

Comment: i AM not asking you people to implement whole code for me.... i just want to clear my logic.... please refer me a book... i will be thankful to you

Comment: There is this site called Wikipedia, not so many people know about it, but it is sometime useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: @SalmanKarim questions asking for a book referral are not considered appropriate for SO; they are "not constructive" by the site's guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is :

1°/ Find the position where you want to Insert or Delete.

2°/ Save the next node to link it to the new node (Insertion) or to the previous node (Deletion)

It should look like this for the Insertion :

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }

    public void InsertAt(string name, int index, Node start)
    {
        Node current = start;
        // Skip nodes until you reach the position
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }
        // Save next node
        Node next = current.Next;
        // Link a new Node which next Node is the one you just saved
        current.Next = new Node () { Name = name, Next = next };
    }
}
```

Now try yourself for the Deletion :).

Comment: You really shouldn't answer such questions, you only encourage this type of bad behavior.  You also explain nothing and just provide the code, which isn't appropriate in this context.

Comment: Is this really worth a downvote ? I believe there is no stupid question ...

Comment: I didn't say the question was stupid, I said it shouldn't be answered.  Not every question anyone can ever have should be answered.  It's also not a good answer, independent of the quality of the question.  As I said, it contains no explanation, just code, thus feeding the help vampire.

Comment: First, there are a few explanation in the comments though I think a nice schema could really help enhance the answer. Second, your Answers/Questions ratio speaks for you on the way you think about asking question. Do you feel dirty when you ask ?

Comment: Plus, *Please explain it with a sample code so that i can understand it well*. I provided a sample code which is what the OP wants.

Comment: I find value in solving my own problems yes.  I also don't come across very many problems these days that I can't solve myself.  When I do, I usually don't go to SO first, I go to coworkers or other knowledgeable programmers that I know.  As to your quote of the OP, he was asking for an explanation *augmented with code*, not just code.  I'm not saying you shouldn't provide any code, I'm saying that you should have written an explanation if you wanted to post an answer.  Whether or not you agree with the sentiment, SO's guidelines have strict quality standards for questions.